# React Native - react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I just clone a new React Native project. And though I tried many stack overflow solutions, even though those weren't helpful to me, I am still receiving this error while executing this.

followed these solution but those not helpful from stack overflow

1. npx jetify
2. cd android && ./gradlew clean
3. rm -rf node_modules && yarn install && react-native run-android

node version

```
$ node --version
v14.17.0
```

java version

```
java version "1.8.0_202"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)
```

gradle version

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.7.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-11-16 17:09:24 UTC
Revision:     2972ff02f3210d2ceed2f1ea880f026acfbab5c0

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on May 10 2020
JVM:          1.8.0_202 (Oracle Corporation 25.202-b08)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

package.json versions

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"react-native-reanimated": "2.9.1",
```

Here i paste error message

```
> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
No AAR for react-native-reanimated found. Attempting to build from source.
Native libs debug enabled: false
Android gradle plugin: 4.1.1
Gradle: 6.7.1
building Reanimated2

The Kotlin Gradle plugin was loaded multiple times in different subprojects, which is not supported and may break the build.
This might happen in subprojects that apply the Kotlin plugins with the Gradle 'plugins { ... }' DSL if they specify explicit versions, even if the versions are equal.
Please add the Kotlin plugin to the common parent project or the root project, then remove the versions in the subprojects.
If the parent project does not need the plugin, add 'apply false' to the plugin line.
See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl
The Kotlin plugin was loaded in the following projects: ':react-native-pager-view', ':react-native-webview'

> Task :react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
341 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 339 up-to-date
C:\Users\demo\Desktop\project\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\reanimated\layoutReanimation\ReanimatedUIImplementation.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
      ViewManagerResolver viewManagerResolver,
      ^
  symbol:   class ViewManagerResolver
  location: class ReanimatedUIImplementation
C:\Users\demo\Desktop\project\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\reanimated\layoutReanimation\ReanimatedUIImplementation.java:11: error: recursive constructor invocation
  public ReanimatedUIImplementation(
         ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

Comment: have you added  plugins: [
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
 in babel.config.js file

Comment: yes added in babel.config.js